# hudson ci doesn't run ant scripts when building

Tags: ant, hudson, java

I have set up hudson to download the specific jdk and ant version my ant scripts uses.
i have added "invoke ant" script under "build" on the project configuration page and set it to use the jdk and ant version i wanted.

still, when building, all hudson does is to checkout from the svn and thats it, build successful.

am i missing something ?

thanks !

build log:

> Started by user xxx.xxx
>
> Updating
>   http://...............................
>   (i've omitted the path)
>
> U
>   installation/antinstaller/resources/jboss.zip
>   U
>   server/db/analytics/sequences/SEQ_SUI_APPLICATIONS.sql
>
> At revision 18537
>
> Finished: SUCCESS

here is my configuration page
[image: configuration page]

[image: build configuration]

Comment: Add build log, the checkout may be failing

Comment: @frisco i've added the console output (is that what you mean as build log ?), very short one since there was almost nothing to update from the repository

Comment: Yes I was asking for that. I am not sure but probably the problem are the build steps that are misconfigured, recheck the ant step and the path to be sure the ant script is there. You should check the workspace and check if it is where you are telling hime.

Comment: i don't know what i'm doing wrong and the log file is not detailed at all. just says build successful but it's not very helpful

Comment: problem fixed. i have deleted the job and created it again and this time it recognized that i had ant script waiting to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

By creating a new project from scratch and then compare the config.xml in the jobs directory, I found that the problem with my first object was the following:

Somehow it had the tag <matrix-project> instead of <project> even though this was not visible in the HTML configuration. With the help of a search and replace tool like [TextCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler) - which is the easiest way to deal with a lot of projects anyway - I got it working.